# How can tell maven to use Java5 rather than Java6?

Tags: java, maven

Hi I have a multimodule Maven project and i installed **Java1.5** and **Java1.6** in my **Windows** machine and Path set for **Java1.6** in Environment variable(For Eclipse Juno).But i will want to run maven command with **Java5** only.How can i set in Parent project pom to use **Java5** only for compiling Java files .I added these lines in parent pom.xm file.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

But i am getting error in chile project pom.xml file

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile
>   (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)

Comment: Is it when you build that you get the error?

Comment: No My pom.xml showing this error inside eclipse

Comment: Note that this will still compile with the javac found in JAVA_HOME just passed some options.  If you explicitly need the compiler to run in Java 5 you must use extra voodoo to tell Maven where to find it.

Comment: Is it only the above error or have you pasted only part of the error? If so, can you give the full error message?

Comment: I am getting this exception without running any maven command by default child pom.xml showing this exception on mouse over.

Comment: Eclipse compiler? Couldn't it be eclipse plugin [feature](http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered)?

Comment: I did not get your point @default locale?

Comment: @subodh, it seems m2eclipse used to generate similar error message for plugins without configuration mapping. Check out the link in my previous comment.

Comment: compiler:compile showing error as i saw maven life cycle in eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Plugin_Management instead of Plugins declaration this declaration need to inherit plugins configuration to child projects (http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management)

in you case it will be looks in the following manner:

**parent** *pom.xml*

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.1</version>
          <configuration>
             <source>1.5</source>
             <target>1.5</target>
          </configuration>
       </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**child** pom.xml

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Also it is possible to set the following properties in **parent** *pom.xml*

```
<properties>
   <maven.compiler.source>1.5</maven.compiler.source>
   <maven.compiler.target>1.5</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Comment: Hmm same as i did for dependency.

Comment: It sounds like a good recommendation for maven users, but does it answer the question? I mean, does the error mentioned in the question has something to do with plugin management?

Comment: I added as u mentioned but still i am getting exception in child pom.xml file

Comment: Can you please edit your answer ? So that it will cleat to me and everyone which entry we have to do in parent Pom.xml and child Pom.xml file .
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. Can you please let me know one more thing if i am running mvn install from command prompt which is showing java -version (1.6) my maven will compile java file from 1.5 or 1.6 as we already define inside pom.xml use 1.5 rather than 1.6?

Comment: I am accepting your answer but i have to change my class path entry and make it java1.5 rather than 1.6 to run mvn clean install from command prompt

Comment: It will use pom.xml setting on mvn install also (in your case 1.5)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a problem related to compiling test sources.

Try to add the `testSource` and `testTarget` to the configuration too:

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>eclipse</compilerId>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
                <testSource>1.5</testSource>
                <testTarget>1.5</testTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

---

**Edit**

It seems to be a well-known problem and you'll have to do some configuration of the m2e plugin. This eclipse site has some information: http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered

Something like this has to be added in the parent pom under the `build` tag:

```
<pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test-compile</goal>
                                    <goal>compile</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <execute/>
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

I am not really an eclipse user so don't ask me why this has to be done but this should do it.

Comment: Sorry but i have no any test class in my project.And one more thing i have to add these entries in all pom.xml file or only in parent pom.xml file.

Comment: Sorry @maba but i am still getting same error on parent tag of child Pom.xml file